# Why is the simulation of a self hold circuit in Altium is so hard?

Tags: relay, simulation, altium, spice

I'm trying to simulate a self-holding circuit that is part of a multi-sheet project, but no matter how I try to run the simulation, it doesn't behave as it is supposed to.

I've isolated the circuit from the rest with its own sources, also tried to run it as a document and as part of the project, with no success.

The purpose is simple: there are two sources, one is a pulse and one is a static DC source. A DPST relay gets a pulse on its coil, and one pole is used to feed the rest of the circuit from the static source, while the second pole is used to feed the relay coil from the static source without the need of the pulse source.

What is supposed to happen is that when I monitor the voltages Vsource, Vtrigger, and Vout, I should see that Vsource is steady on 12V, Vtrigger is giving me a pulse, and Vout is low until the Vtrigger goes high, and after that Vout stays on 12V after the Vtrigger goes down again.

What happens is that after many tries and debugging the circuit I've come up with two wrong behaviors: Vout goes high at T=0, or Vout is High if and only if Vtirgger is high (Vout goes down after Vtrigger goes down.)

I'm adding a picture of my circuit:

[image]

The two nets in the middle go to a connector port that is under compile mask, in reality, it would connect to external NO-button.

Unless it is a specific tutorial for what I'm trying to do, please don't send me documentation or tutorials. I'm getting close to my deadline and I spent many hours trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Just a suggestion: If you can export the image itself on the PC and use *that* in your question, instead of a photo of the screen, that will help - some readers will just "skip" your question due to the difficult-to-view screen photo. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: The relay appears to connect V12TEST to Vtestpulse when operated. Is this what you intended? What are the properties of V12TEST and Vtestpulse?

Comment: Vtestpulse's purpose is to trigger the relay coil via a short 12v pulse, while V12Test gives a steady 12V.